# Using Mapbox like basemap in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, wms, mapbox, wmts

Iam using ArcGIS Desktop 10.3 with a Basic level license.

Working on different projects, with different data, for different locations. For the most part I get vector data like parcels and buildings for the area of interest and thats it. But to publish also nice looking maps I have to use ***Esri basemaps/ services.arcgis.online*** like their *topographic map* or ***OpenStreetMap*** wms data too. Basically, I am satisfied with the layout of this basemaps (streetnames, hillshade, waters, forrest etc.), but it could be better. For example if I want to show the landuse or points of interest of an area it could be confusing for the reader of the map because in the Esri basemap you can find landuse (in the OSM basemap you can find POIs) too.

On the other hand you have nice looking tools like ***Mapbox***, wich allow you to manipulate the layout of the map, for example you can turn off the landuse or the POIs.

Is it possible to use a self builded map style from Mapbox like a basemap or a wms service in ***ArcGIS 10.x*** *for Desktop*?

Answer (score 1):

MapBox has posted [Add Mapbox maps as layers in ArcGIS and QGIS with WMTS](https://www.mapbox.com/help/mapbox-arcgis-qgis/):

> Mapbox provides a number of handy, pre-built URLs and code snippets to
>   help you add your custom Mapbox maps to other mapping tools. This
>   tutorial will show you how you can add any Mapbox map as a layer in
>   ArcMap or QGIS as WMTS.